# BeautifulSoup scrape only few positions

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning web scraping.

Few month ago I did some scraping for learning purpose website with house prices. It is on github:
https://github.com/MariuszTP/Beautifulsoup

Now when I try to scrape it, it is returning only few positions.

I simplify the code:

```
url = "https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/poznan?distanceRadius=0&market=ALL&locations=%5Bcities_6-1%5D&viewType=listing&lang=pl&searchingCriteria=sprzedaz&searchingCriteria=mieszkanie&searchingCriteria=cala-polska"


html_text = requests.get( url ).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml') 
houses = soup.find_all('article', class_ = 'css-n8rq67 es62z2j16')
for i in houses:
    print(i.text)
```

Can somebody tell me please what is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Today most of the websites not have the data in the HTML directly. It means that BeautifulSoup cannot work with dynamic websites. (Selenium is the solution)

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
URL = 'https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/poznan?distanceRadius=0&market=ALL&locations=%5Bcities_6-1%5D&viewType=listing&lang=pl&searchingCriteria=sprzedaz&searchingCriteria=mieszkanie&searchingCriteria=cala-polska'
driver.get(URL)
houses = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//article[@class='css-n8rq67 es62z2j16']")
for i in houses:
    print(i.text) 
print(len(houses))
driver.quit()
```